# Problems upgrading Media from 8.3 to 8.5

Tags: 8, media

I have a Drupal 8.5.3 site (built from [the composer project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)) that was previously on the 8.3 branch before the critical security updates forced me to update to 8.5. One of the things I missed in the upgrade is that the Media module has moved to core and has [its own upgrade instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/media/faq-transition-from-media-entity-to-media-in-core#upgrade-instructions-from-media-entity-contrib-to-media-in-core). So as I look through those instructions, I have steps 1-5 covered and need to upgrade the codebase. I should also say that the site has heavy usage of the Media module with content and paragraph fields.

So after going through the process[1] of getting the right versions of the right modules in place, when I try to `updb`, I get this error message:

```
In order to run the Media Entity 2.x upgrade, please uninstall and remove from the codebase the contributed "Media" module.
Before continuing, please make sure all modules that provide plugins for Media Entity (or depend on it) have their code updated to their respective 2.x branches. Note that you will probably need to revert to the 1.x branch of the Media Entity module if you want to uninstall existing plugin modules. The following modules depend on media entity and need to be either upgraded or uninstalled: media.
```

If I do a `cr` or try to `pm-uninstall media`, I get a long error message[3].

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get updated? I feel like this is quite a mess and I wonder if it'd be better to spin up a new 8.5.3 site and migrate content over. Though I'm sure I would run into configuration problems with my existing sets of media fields.

### Update

Thanks to [@sonfd](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/48114/sonfd)'s clue, I was finally able to get this upgraded. It was a pretty tedious process that I'm going to lay out in a blog post soon.

### Update 2

Wrote up [a blog post](https://blog.purdy.info/2018/06/upgrading-drupal-from-83-to-85.html) to lay out how I resolved this issue. Maybe it will help others. Definitely lays out my newly-gained scar from not reading upgrade instructions and changelogs more closely.

[1]:

```
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer remove drupal/media
# (NOTE: If I don't remove drupal/media first, I get a composer install error[2])
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require \
  drupal/inline_entity_form drupal/crop:2.x-dev drupal/media_entity_instagram:2.x-dev \
  drupal/media_entity:2.x-dev drupal/media_entity_slideshow:2.x-dev \
  drupal/media_entity_twitter:2.x-dev drupal/slick_media:2.x-dev \
  drupal/media_entity_actions
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer remove drupal/video_embed_field
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require drupal/media
```

[2]:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/image_widget_crop 2.1.0 requires drupal/crop 1.0 - 2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/crop[1.x-dev].
    - drupal/image_widget_crop 2.1.0 requires drupal/crop 1.0 - 2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/crop[1.x-dev].
    - drupal/image_widget_crop 2.1.0 requires drupal/crop 1.0 - 2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/crop[1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/crop[1.x-dev, 2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal/crop 2.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/crop[2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal/image_widget_crop (locked at 2.1.0) -> satisfiable by drupal/image_widget_crop[2.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

[3]:

```
$ ../vendor/bin/drush pm-uninstall media
Error: Call to a member function addConstraint() on null in          [error]
media_entity_type_alter() (line 72 of
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/modules/contrib/media/media.module)
#0
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(539):
media_entity_type_alter(Array, NULL, NULL)
#1
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(333):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter('entity_type', Array)
#2
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php(117):
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->alterDefinitions(Array)
#3
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(175):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions()
#4
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeRepository.php(83):
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions()
#5
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php(523):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeRepository->getEntityTypeFromClass('Drupal\\user\\Ent...')
#6
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/User/User8.php(26):
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity::load(0)
#7
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot.php(558):
Drush\User\User8->load_by_uid(0)
#8
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(354):
Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_drupal_login()
#9
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(473):
drush_bootstrap(6, 6)
#10
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(59):
drush_bootstrap_to_phase(6)
#11
/Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#12 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12):
drush_main()
#13 {main}.
Error: Call to a member function addConstraint() on null in /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/modules/contrib/media/media.module on line 72 #0 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(539): media_entity_type_alter(Array, NULL, NULL)
#1 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(333): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter('entity_type', Array)
#2 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php(117): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->alterDefinitions(Array)
#3 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(175): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->findDefinitions()
#4 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeRepository.php(83): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions()
#5 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php(523): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeRepository->getEntityTypeFromClass('Drupal\\user\\Ent...')
#6 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/User/User8.php(26): Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity::load(0)
#7 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot.php(558): Drush\User\User8->load_by_uid(0)
#8 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(354): Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_drupal_login()
#9 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(473): drush_bootstrap(6, 6)
#10 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(59): drush_bootstrap_to_phase(6)
#11 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#12 /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#13 {main}
Error: Call to a member function addConstraint() on null in media_entity_type_alter() (line 72 of /Users/jason/Sites/artobject/web/modules/contrib/media/media.module).
```

Comment: My interpretation of [the media upgrade instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/media/faq-transition-from-media-entity-to-media-in-core#upgrade-instructions-from-media-entity-contrib-to-media-in-core) are that you should not run db updates until step 8. Have you run `drush mecu` (step 7) to check that your have configured things properly?

Comment: I'm having problems with step 8. If I try `drush mecu`, I get the same error as [3], with the addConstraint() issue.

Comment: Did you have the core media module installed before running `drush updb`? which version of drush are you using?

Comment: Yes, the core media module was installed before running `drush updb`. I am using version 8.1.17. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to uninstall and remove from the codebase the contrib media module before doing this update.

On the [contrib media module's project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) they state:

> Drupal core version 8.4 now includes a media module with similar functionality. In #2831274: Bring Media entity module to core as Media module core adopted media namespace to add support for full-featured media entities. In case you are using the 8.3.x contrib media on your sites you need to uninstall it and remove it from the codebase before updating to Drupal 8.4.

Comment: Thank you for this, sonfd. This ended up being a major clue that got me to the rest. I'll have to update my question with the final answer.